# Recaptcha V3 with livewire contact form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, contact-form

Could I possibly get some help with a contact form? I've integrated recaptcha following this article: https://blog.livewiretoolkit.com/using-google-recaptcha-with-laravel-8-and-laravel-livewire.

When I test it, the error messages display

> Class "App\Http\Livewire\Http" not found

and laravel does not seem to understand `$response = Http::post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . env('CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY') . '&response=' . $token);`

I don't understand what I've done wrong as I'm trying to validate recaptcha within livewire.

Here is the rest of my code:

Blade file

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="send" method="POST" id="contactForm">

{{ csrf_field() }}

@if(session()->has('success'))

    <h3 class="title is-size-5 has-text-success">{{ session('success') }}</h3> 

@endif


<fieldset wire:loading.attr="disabled" wire:loading.remove wire:target="send">

    <div class="columns">

        <div class="column is-half">
        <!--Name field-->
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Name</label>

                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input is-small @error('name') is-danger @enderror" type="text" name="name" wire:model.debounce.365ms="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name">

                            @error('name')<p class="help is-danger">{{ $message }}</p>@enderror
                    </div>
            </div><!-- field -->
        </div><!---column is half-->

        <div class="column">
        <!--Email field-->
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Email</label>

                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input is-small @error('email') is-danger @enderror" type="email" name="email" id="email" wire:model.debounce.365ms="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address">

                            @error('email')<p class="help is-danger">{{ $message }}</p>@enderror
                    </div>
            </div><!-- field -->
        </div><!---column-->

    </div><!---columns-->

        <!--Message field-->
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Message</label>

                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea class="textarea @error('message') is-danger @enderror" name="message" wire:model.debounce.365ms="message" id="message" placeholder="Talk to me..."></textarea>

                            @error('message')<p class="help is-danger">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
                    </div>
            </div><!-- field -->
           
            <div class="field is-grouped submit-button">
                <div class="control">
                    <button 

                    wire:target="send" type="submit"
                        data-sitekey="{{env('CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY')}}"
                        data-callback='handle'
                        data-action='submit'
                        class="g-recaptcha button cta">
                        Send Message
                    </button>
                    <!--button wire:loading.class="is-loading" wire:target="send" class="button cta" type="submit" name="submit" id="submitButton">Send Message</button-->
                </div>
            </div><!-- field -->

</fieldset>
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={{env('CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY')}}"></script>
    <script>
        function handle(e) {
            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                grecaptcha.execute('{{env('CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY')}}', {action: 'submit'})
                    .then(function (token) {
                        @this.set('captcha', token);
                    });
            })
        }
    </script>

</form>
```

Livewire component

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Mail\ContactMail;
use App\Models\Contact;
use App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $email;
    public $name;
    public $message;
    public $captcha = 0;
   
    public function rules()
    {
        return (new ContactFormRequest())->rules();
    }

    protected $messages = [
        'name.required' => 'Please provide your name',
        'name.min' => 'Please provide at least 2 letters',
        'email.required' => 'Please provide your email',
        'email.email' => 'This Email Address is not valid',
        'message.required' => 'Please provide your message',
    ];

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    public function updatedCaptcha($token)
    {
        $response = Http::post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . env('CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY') . '&response=' . $token);
        $this->captcha = $response->json()['score'];

        if (!$this->captcha > .3) {
            $this->send();
        } else {
            return session()->flash('success', 'Google thinks you are a bot, please refresh and try again');
        }

    }

    public function send()
    {
        $validated = $this->validate();
        // save to mysql database
        Contact::create($validated);
        // send email
        Mail::to('email.com')->send(new ContactMail($validated));
        // clear form
        $this->reset();
        // display success message
        session()->flash('success','Thank you for your message');
        //dd($validated); <!-- Will Delete Later-->
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.contact-form');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you have to import the classes you wish to use. If you do not specify a path or import the class, it will assume that the class exists in the current folder/namespace.

Hence, to use the `Http` facade, you have to import it. You can do this either by using it in the top, or inline.

You can apply either of these below (place them at the top of your file, near the other `use` statements). Both of these are the same class, as the `use Http` is an alias for `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http`.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
// or
use Http;
```

*Some IDE's prefer you use the full path when using the class, while others will understand both*

Comment: Update, I discovered I'd made a typo in public function updatedCaptcha($token). The secret key did not match how it was spelled in the ENV file, I've changed it to read CAPTCHA_SITE_SECRET instead.

However, there is still a problem with the form. The error message saying 'Google thinks you are a bot' shows up, and the emails do not send